# How to put events for items in drawer layout?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a drawer layout in my project.

I want to put some events by clicking the item in  drawerlayout.

I think I should use `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)` Method but I don't know how to do that.

For example I want to show a dialog after clicking one of these items and show some text views and put a button to lead users to my website.

Or I want to lead them to another activity by pushing one of these items.

Comment: Show the example screen of what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to you don't get confused while write the code, i suggest you use the default navigation drawer in your apps

```
   @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.your_id){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder1.setMessage("Write your message here.");
            builder1.setCancelable(true);

            builder1.setPositiveButton(
                    "Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            builder1.setNegativeButton(
                    "No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
            alert11.show();


            //or if your want to call new activity, do this just call the intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;

    }
```

and you can find the navigation drawer `id` in `res/menu/activity_main_drawer.xml`

EDITED :
this is how to lead user to your website :

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    String url = "your_website_url";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent); // on fragment do : getActivity.startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

hope it works :)

Comment: and can u help me how to lead the user to my website by adding an button ? :)))

Comment: please see my update answer above, hope it help you.

Comment: @RBesar- @R Besar thanks  but i wanted to put a button in my alert dialog that user click on it and go to my website . do i have any chance?

Comment: I start thinking that you haven't tried by yourself before. Just put `Button` on your layout and give `onClick` function.

Comment: no dear friend !!! i tried a lot but  u know that putting a text in alert dialog dosen't need any button ! i wanna put a text in that  dialog that linked it to my website.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
                int id = item.getItemId();

                if (id == R.id.nav_item_id1) {
                    // Handle the action
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() ,"nav_item_id1 Clicked" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else if (id == R.id.nav_item_id2) {
                // Handle the action

                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() ,"nav_item_id2 clicked" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } 


            }
        }
```

Hope this help s you